# Fetch models from a background thread SwiftData

Tags: swift, swift-data

I don't need to write, I just need to read.

So far I've found [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/736226) link, but I'm still very confused. I've not used `Actors` before, and I'm confused when trying to implement what is explained at that link. So far I haven't been able to get anything they suggest to work.

It seems like this was much simpler using CoreData, as explained [here](https://www.advancedswift.com/core-data-background-fetch-save-create/).

Using the code above, it seems that the `context` and `actor` are both running on a background thread, but it's still crashing. I assume that that's because the `modelContainer` is still on the main thread. At least, I'm assuming that the `modelContainer` is still on the main thread.

How do I fetch `Models` on a background thread in a thread safe way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of ModelContext and use that but otherwise it can be straightforward to not run a fetch on the main thread.

Here is a silly example, a basic class that holds its own instance of a ModelContext and performs a fetch count

```
class Fetcher {
    let context: ModelContext

    init(container: ModelContainer) {
        context = ModelContext(container)
    }

    func getSomeStats() async -> Int {
        do {
            return try context.fetchCount(FetchDescriptor<TransactionDTO>())
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

If you call it like this

```
.task {
    let fetcher = Fetcher(container: modelContext.container)
    let result = await fetcher.getSomeStats()
    print(result)
}
```

and set a breakpoint inside `getSomeStats` you will clearly see it isn't running on the main thread.

Comment: Hey, using actors and such I was able to prove that the actor and context were running on the background thread. This is true. But, the container is bound to the main thread, and that’s the problem. You can’t send the container into the background thread safely. If you change your Xcode settings to have strict concurrency warnings, you’ll see that it gives you a warning passing the container into the .task. That’s the problem.

Comment: I have strict concurrency check enabled and I do not get a warning

Comment: Hmm. Thank you so much! Looking at my code a little more, it looks like the crash was happening because of some other stuff. The thread wasn't even the issue ‍♂️. Thread wise, it was working right all along. Looks like that is the right way to do it, which is nice 'cause it's pretty simple!